# What is the fastest way to count total of rows in mySQL

Tags: mysql, count, row

I need to know what is the fastest way to count the rows of views according to each product. I tried to run the query by join it between two table. A '**product_db**' and '**product_views**'. But it took about a minute to complete a query.

Here is my code:

```
select *,
count(product_views.vwr_id) as product_viewer,
from product_db 
inner join product_viewer on product_db.id=product_views.vwr_cid
where product_id='$pid' order by id desc
```

Where '**$pid**' is a product id.

This is my product_views table.

[image]

I need to include a column of viewers into my table. But it takes very long time to load. I either tried to count a separate query, but no luck. Please you guy suggest a more brilliant way.

Regards,

Comment: Why are you using an aggregate function with no GROUP BY? Do you realize that this will not give you the correct result?

Comment: If you omit the count function, does it still take the same amount of time to run?  I think you may need to index your tables.  Run the same code with an EXPLAIN and it might give you a hint.  Or post the results here and we can help.

Comment: @bluefeet, I've tried either with and without 'group by'. And the result doesn't change - it still slow.

Comment: @Tom, as you can see in my code. The reason behind using '$pid' is it a table. So many product listed in there and you can see how many people view each product by the number. When it loops to show the product it also counts the viewer. At this point, a browser stuck with loading icon runs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your query is slow, not the counting.  Two things you could try:

1. Make sure the product_id field has an index on it.
2. If the product_id is a numeric field, remove the single quotes around it.  In other words change this `where product_id='$pid'` to this `where product_id=$pid`.  MySQL could be doing a conversion on the product_id field to convert it to a string for the comparison and ignoring the index if it does exist.